# Laravel voyager - не работает скрипт для canvas

Tags: laravel, canvas, запрос

не могу разобраться. Есть проект на фрейме laravel. Нашел красивый шаблон с использованием в нем canvas. Ставлю его на чистый фрейм, то норм, если на laravel установить админку voyager, то не работает скрипт. Весь код одинаковый и пути нормально прописаны. Я так понял что это проблема в query, но не могу понять какая.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там выше ошибка `unexpected token ')'` - т.е. ошибка синтаксиса скрипта `demo.js`

Comment: Ошибки не может быть, так как я его не меняя на чистом laravel ставлю и всё работает. Может это из-за конфликтов версий query?

Comment: и тем не менее браузер говорит красным по розовому что там ошибка, на 145 строчке